# my own little chat not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, chat, viewstate

I have made my own little chat. It it basicly a jQuery that reloads a div by inserting another  .aspx site into it.
This is my .aspx site:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/holdOversigt.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="chat.aspx.cs" Inherits="HB.chat1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var reloadtime = 3000;
        function load() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "chat-Content.aspx",
                context: document.body,
                success: function (data) {
                    document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = data;
                    setTimeout('load()', reloadtime);
                }
            });
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            setTimeout('load()', reloadtime);
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #005da3; font-weight: bold">
        <strong>Chat rum</strong></h1>
    <div id="chat" class="fisk" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
    </div>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txbMessege" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="btnSend_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

THis is the site it inserts into the div:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="chat-Content.aspx.cs" Inherits="HB.chat_Content" %>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ListBox ID="lbChat" runat="server" Rows="10" Width="400px"></asp:ListBox>
    </div>
    </form>
```

This is the sites codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace HB
{
    public partial class chat_Content : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        grjenie31Entities gr;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gr = new grjenie31Entities();

            var query = from es in gr.chats
                        where es.id > ((from esh in gr.chats select esh.id).Max() - 15)
                        orderby es.timestamps descending
                        select es;

            List<chat> list = new List<chat>();
            foreach (chat chat in query)
            {
                list.Add(chat);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                lbChat.Items.Add("[" + list[i].timestamps + "] " + list[i].personID.ToString() + ": " + list[i].besked);
            }
            this.lbChat.SelectedIndex = this.lbChat.Items.Count - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I can add new lines until it loads... but when the listbox is showed on the site it give me the follow error:

> The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

Anybody got any idea what i can do about it??

Comment: Take a look at SignalR: http://nuget.org/packages/SignalR

Answer (score 0):

It seems you inserted all page content even `ViewState` hidden tags.
I think it's better to clear your response and write your html tags which you needed in chat.

```
 Response.Clear();
 Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
 Response.Write(GetChatResult());
 Response.End();
```